# Parsing MySQL JSON results in Jquery

Tags: jquery, mysql, json

I'm attempting to parse some JSON results from a MySQL database into a simple HTML table. Currently, I can return the raw JSON  string `data` correctly. However, when I try to parse these results into an HTML table, I am returned 'Undefined'.

**JS File:**

```
$('input#name-submit').on('click', function() {
var name = $('input#name').val();
if ($.trim(name) != '') {
$.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data) {
 var tr;
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].ARTIST + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].LOCATION + "</td>");
        $('table').append(tr);
        }
});
}

});
```

**table from HTML file:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>ARTIST</th>
    <th>LOCATION</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Edited:**

**The JSON results, being returned as 'Undefined' in my index file**

`{"ARTIST":"Katy Perry","LOCATION":"United States"}`

Comment: About the table HTML... the first part should be enclosed in a <thead> element rather than <tr>. Then, <tbody> for the content.

Comment: Offtopic, but this might be interesting for you: http://handlebarsjs.com/

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is intelligent about determining the return type of ajax requests based on a lot of factors.  In this case, I'm almost positive that `data` has already been parsed.  If you remove the `sentdata` line and just use `data` instead, your code should work as you intend.

See the [`dataType` property for ajax for jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Ah yes I thought this line could be surplus to requirements. I've removed it, however, i'm now only being returned an 'undefined' result from the JSON in each column.

Comment: @Byate have you inspected the return from your Ajax request in firebug/Web Inspector/F12 tools?

Comment: I've inspected in Firebug and the JSON is loading as inspected. It's parsing it into the HTML table where the problem begins, resulting in 'Undefined' results

Comment: @Byate *when* does it return "'Undefined' results?"

Comment: This is displayed when I view my index file in my browser. When debugging the page, the page is successfully returning the JSON data but displaying it as 50 'Undefined' records where the parsed JSON data should be. Stumped!

Comment: Did you remove the call to `parseJSON`?  That was the point of my answer

Comment: I did indeed. I get the feeling I need to add something to define the data as JSON in my `$.post('ajax/name.php', {name: name}, function(data)` line but I've not been able to figure out where

Answer (score 1):

An exammple is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nqRk9/2/

if your data is:

`{"ARTIST":"Katy Perry","LOCATION":"United States"}`

You could just do this without the for loop:

```
    tr = $('<tr/>');
    tr.append("<td>" + data.ARTIST + "</td>");
    tr.append("<td>" + data.LOCATION + "</td>");
    $('#single').append(tr);
```

But if you were to have more artists and locations here is an example of what your data could look like.

```
{"ARTIST":[["Katy Perry"], ["Artist 2"], ["Artist 3"]],"LOCATION":[["United States"],["Location 2"], ["Location 3"]]};
```

And here's how you could access the data:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.ARTIST.length; ++i)
{
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data.ARTIST[i] + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data.LOCATION[i] + "</td>");
        $('#multiple').append(tr);
}
```

I believe that your array subscript is in the wrong place, In the OP.

Comment: Thanks - it didn't solve the particular problem I had but this is a nice way of doing it and i've adapted it into my code. I added a variable `var sentdata=JSON.parse(data)` just before the `for` loop and and changed `data` to `sentdata`. This now parses the data as desired.